# Show max $\lVert proj_{w^\perp} u_i \rVert^2 = 1, \quad \lVert u_i \rVert = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

given an orthonormal basis $w_1,...,w_k$ for $w^\perp$ and a unit vector $u_i$, how can I show that $$0 \le\lVert proj_{w^\perp} u_i \rVert^2 = \lVert \sum_{j=1}^k \langle u_i, w_j \rangle w_j \rVert ^2 \le 1 $$ ?

What I have tried is this
$$ \lVert \sum_{j=1}^k \langle u_i, w_j \rangle w_j \rVert  \le 
 \sum_{j=1}^k \lVert \langle u_i, w_j \rangle w_j \rVert  = \sum_{j=1}^m \lvert \langle u_i ,w_j \rangle \rvert \lVert w_j \rVert =  \sum_{j=1}^m \lvert \langle u_i ,w_j \rangle \rvert$$
How can that last sum be shown to be  less than or equal to 1?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
\Big\| \sum^k_{j=1}\langle u_i, w_j\rangle w_j\Big\|^2 = \sum^k_{j=1}|\langle u_i, w_j\rangle|^2  \leq \|u_i\|^2 = 1. 
\end{align}